# Reflect changes on updates with React Hook Forms

Tags: reactjs, refresh, updates, react-hook-form

I'm encountering an issue while working with React (utilizing React Hook Form, TypeScript, and ShadcnUI) on the front end and Laravel on the back end.

The problem revolves around input fields unexpectedly "resetting" when I navigate between components.

While I am able to successfully update my user data, an unexpected behavior occurs when I switch to another component and then return to the user profile update form. Instead of displaying the recently updated data, the form reverts to displaying the old data.

I suspect that the root cause of this behavior lies in the usage of "defaultValue." Despite my attempts to resolve this issue, I have not been successful in finding a solution.

```
import axios from "@/api/axios";
import ErrorMessage from "@/components/common/ErrorMessage";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import useAuthContext from "@/context/AuthContext";
import { PersonnalInformationValues } from "@/lib/auth/dashboard/typePersonnalInformationForm";
import { ProfileSettingsProps } from "@/lib/auth/dashboard/typeProfileSettingsProps";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";



type FormErrors = {
email?: string[];
name?: string[];
last_name?: string[];
};

function PersonalInformation(props: ProfileSettingsProps) {
 const [errors, setErrors] = useState<FormErrors>({});
 const { formLoading, setFormLoading } = props;
 const userData = props.user;
 const csrfData = props.csrf;
 const { t } = useTranslation()

 const { user, getUser, csrf, userLoading, hasRole } = useAuthContext() as AuthContextType;



const [email, setEmail] = useState(userData.email);
useEffect(() => {
  setEmail(user.email);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setErrors({});
    // setLoading(false);
  }, 600);
}, [user.email]);


const personnalInformationForm = useForm<PersonnalInformationValues>({
  defaultValues: {
    email: userData.email,
    last_name: userData.last_name,
    name: userData.name,
    // avatar: "",
  },
});


const onSubmitPersonnalInformationForm = async (values: PersonnalInformationValues) => {
  setFormLoading(true);
  await csrfData();
  setErrors({});
  try {
    const response = await axios.put(`/api/user/${userData.id}`, values);
    console.log(response)
    if(response.data.message === 'Profil mis à jour avec succès') {
      successToast(t('profile:update_success'))
    }


  } catch (error: any) {
    errorToast(t('common:something_went_wrong'))
    console.log(error);
    if(error.response.status === 422) {
      setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
    }  
  } finally {
    setFormLoading(false);
  }
}

return (
    <Form {...personnalInformationForm}>
      <form onSubmit={personnalInformationForm.handleSubmit(onSubmitPersonnalInformationForm)} className="md:col-span-2">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:max-w-xl sm:grid-cols-6">
          <div className="sm:col-span-3">
            <FormField
            control={personnalInformationForm.control}
            name="last_name"
            render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                <FormLabel className='capitalize'>{t('register:last_name')}</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                    <Input placeholder={t('register:last_name_placeholder')}
                    type='text'
                    {...field} 
                    />
                </FormControl>
                {errors.last_name  &&
                  <ErrorMessage 
                    message={errors.last_name[0]}
                  />
                }
                </FormItem>
            )}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div className="mt-8 flex">
          <Button disabled={formLoading} type='submit' variant="dark" className='text-white disabled:bg-customYellow disabled:text-customBlack'>
            {formLoading ? (
              <Loader2 className="animate-spin"/>
            ) : (
              <span>{t('common:save')}</span>
            )}
            
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Form>
)
}

 export default PersonalInformation
```

I only let you the last_name to have the readable code as possible.

I tried to put de defaultValues, into an useState, then pass the setData into the useEffect, but it didn't worked.

Have you some idea?